# ubuntu desktop can't reach most websites

Tags: networking

I've just installed Ubuntu on an a reconditioned desktop, and am using an Ethernet to Wireless converter (plugs into Ehternet port and then that connects to my ATT wireless home router). I am not sure if the last network detail matters but for some reason most of the websites that I try to access from Google search are not accessable. I can get to major websites but none of the others like stack overflow etc cannot  be reached. Do you know why this is the case? I've used ubuntu on another laptop and have never experienced antying like this.

Comment: What release did you install?  Are you on an unrestricted network? or is your network in a corporate/education/etc environment where traffic is controlled/censored?  Did you perform any exploration? (via `ping` etc) if so why not tell us.

Comment: Does your AT&T have a DSL modem? Install `iputils-tracepath` and then edit your question and show me the output of `tracepath www.google.com`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: If google  works you internet is probably working okay. Does welknown websites, like news media or similar work too ? What country are you in, are there any firewall restrictions on your connection ?

Answer (score 0):

According to a VERY smart tech at the local ALTEX store in Dallas (yes this is a plug for their Linux expertise), the DNSSEC setting had to be disabled. For example:

"cd /etc/systemd/"
"sudo gedit resolved.conf"
...
uncomment this line / remove # : "#DNSSEC=no"

Comment: If the line "DNSSEC=no" is commented then it means, by common Linux convention, that it's a default value and does not need to be specified explicitly. So if uncommenting that line changes anything, it means you have set DNSSEC to yes in some other place. Why and how did you do this?